# Return the string with the highest occurrence of a specific character

Tags: python

Given a string like "abbbd cdda cbaa", how would you determine the word that has the highest occurrence of a specific character like "b". My initial code:

```
sample = "abbbd cdda cbaa"
sample_splitter = sample.split()
#sample_splitter is now [abbbd, cdda, cbaa]
for word in sample_splitter:
  word.count("b") #this returns the number of occurrences of the char b
  max(word.count("b")) #this will return the highest number
```

I'm stuck in figuring out how to associate the highest count of the letter and the array value associated with it. In this case that should be **"abbbd"**

Comment: Are you asking how to logically put this together? the most obvious would be to create a list `results` and in your for loop append the result to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

something like this: use `max()` with `str.split()`:

```
>>> strs= "abbbd cdda cbaa"
>>> max(strs.split(),key=lambda x:x.count("b"))
'abbbd'
```

Comment: Superb answer, I've not really tinkered with lambda but this will definitely make me have a second look.

Comment: A problem with this is that if you pass any char value it always returns the first item in the array after the split:
max(strs.split(),key=lambda x:x.count("x"))
'abbbd'

Comment: @jwesonga that's because `"x"` is not in any of the items so this actually becomes `max([0,0,0])`, that is why it return the first one.

Answer (score 0):

The `collections` library contains the useful class `Counter` that can also be used to count the most common elements in a collection.

```
>>> import collections
>>> sample = "abbbd cdda cbaa"
>>> collections.Counter(sample).most_common(1)
[('a', 4)]
```

Note that the argument specifies the number of elements to be returned (from most to least common) - in this case only the most common is needed.